# Read plist into specific type

Tags: arrays, swift, types, properties

When using this:

```
let cities: [[String : String]] = {
    guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cities", withExtension: "plist") else {
        return []
    }
    return NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as! [[String : String]]
}()
```

from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Allentown, PA</string>
        <key>icao</key>
        <string>ABE</string>
    </dict>
    ....
</array>
</plist>
```

it is easy to later access the values using:

```
    // inside tableView(_ cellForRowAt:)
    city = cities[indexPath.row]
    cell.icaoLabel?.text = city["icao"]
    cell.nameLabel?.text = city["name"]
```

However, when declaring:

```
class City {
    var icao: String
    var name: String

    // is this init() necessary?
    init(icao: String, name: String) {
        self.icao = icao
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

and:

```
let cities: [City] = {
    guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cities", withExtension: "plist") else {
        return []
    }
    // ** No longer works
    return NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as! [City]
    // ** Doesn't work either
    return NSArray(contentsOf: URL)
}()
```

Ultimately, I want to use:

```
    // inside tableView(_cellForRowAt:)
    city = cities[indexPath.row]
    cell icaoLabel?.text = city.icao
    cell nameLabel?.text = city.name
```

How is this accomplished?  Can the plist be imported this way?

**Edit to the City class**:

```
class City {
    var icao: String?
    var name: String?

    init(icao: String, name: String) {
        self.icao = icao
        self.name = name
    }

    static func loadCities() -> [City] {
        guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cities", withExtension: "plist") else {
            return []
        }
        let tempCities = NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as! [[String : String]]

        // now, create the desired cities array
        var cities = [City]()
        for city in tempCities {
            guard let icaoTemp = city["icao"], let nameTemp = city["name"] else {
                break
            }
            cities.append(City(icao: icaoTemp, name: nameTemp))
        }

        return cities
    }
}
```

accessing the values:

```
    let city: City = cities[indexPath.row]
    cell.icaoLabel?.text = city.icao
    cell.airportNameLabel?.text = city.name
```

Comment: Do not edit your question with an answer. It negates the whole point of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built in way to convert the plist data directly into an array of your `City` objects. You need to do that yourself.

Load the plist just as you are now. Then iterate that array getting each little dictionary. Either extract the two values and create a `City` instance using your current `init` or add a new `init` that takes a dictionary and let the `City` class set itself up.

In the end you build a new array with each of those `City` instances you create as you iterate the original plist array.

It probably makes sense to wrap all of that functionality up into a `Cities` class that knows how to read and write the plist file and work with the list of `City` instances. You may end up adding other appropriate logic to the class to work with the list of cities.

Comment: Regarding your comment above "Better yet, safely unwrap...", please critique edit (new at bottom of OP)

Answer (score 1):

`[[String: String]]` is a type of an array of `dictionary`. However, your `City` class is just an object containing two `String` objects, it's not a `dictionary` type. So you cannot cast it.

```
let cities: [City] = {
    guard let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cities", withExtension: "plist")     else {
        return []
    }
    var cities = [City]()
    let myCites = NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as! [[String : String]]

    for city in myCites {
        cities.append(City(icao: city["icao"], name: city["name"]))
    }
    return cities
}()
```

Comment: This won't compile as-is because `city["someKey"]` returns an optional value but the `City init` method doesn't accept optionals.

Comment: That's the definition of  `City`. If the `city["someKey"]` is an optional, you should define `someKey: String?`

Comment: Better yet, safely unwrap the values from the dictionary since the parameters to the `City init` should not be optional.

Comment: Trying to learn here.  You say `City` is not a type, it's a `Class`.  From Apple docs on Value and Reference type: `... The second, “reference types”, where instances share a single copy of the data, and the type is usually defined as a class.`  Seeing this, do you still say City is not a type?

Comment: Yep, it's a `refrence types`, which means it references to an `object`. Also, I update the desciption above.